# I have successly logged in a User but Auth::check() and Auth::user() don't seem to be working

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I have successfully authenticated a login user with Laravel 5.4 using `LoginController` and have an event listener that let's me know I have done this. However in my I am trying to check `Auth::guest()` to dynamically display a logged in user's view or a guest user's view. However, I am always seeing a guest user's view.

`LoginController:`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
     use AuthenticatesUsers;

     protected $redirectTo = '/register';

     public function __construct()
     {
          $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
     }

     public function username()
     {
         return 'username';
     }
 }
```

`Config/Auth:`

```
 <?php

     return [


     'defaults' => [
         'guard' => 'web',
         'passwords' => 'user',
      ],

      'guards' => [
         'web' => [
             'driver' => 'session',
             'provider' => 'user',
         ],

         'api' => [
             'driver' => 'token',
             'provider' => 'user',
         ],
      ],

      'providers' => [
           'user' => [
               'driver' => 'eloquent',
               'model' => App\User::class,
            ],
      ],


      'passwords' => [
           'user' => [
               'provider' => 'user',
               'table' => 'password_resets',
               'expire' => 60,
           ],
       ],
  ];
```

`Routes/Web:`

```
      Route::get('/test', 'TestController@test');

      Auth::routes();
```

`app.blade:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/all.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                        {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @if (!Auth::check())
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">{{Auth::check()}}</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    {{ Auth::user() }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`RouteServiceProvider:`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::group(array(
            'middleware' => ['web', 'auth'],
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        ), function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/web.php');
        });

    }

    /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
}
```

`Http\Kernal:`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Are you applying the auth middleware to your routes requiring authentication post-login?

Comment: Can you show me an example and I can check to see if I am? If it is something I should be closely aware of then I probably have not.

Comment: See my answer for an example @Alex Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my RouteServiceProvider this function loads the bulk of my applications routes

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::group(array(
        'middleware' => ['web', 'auth'],
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ), function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/web.php');
    });
}
```

Then in app/Http/Kernel I have

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth'              => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic'        => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
];
```

Notice the `'middleware' => ['web', 'auth'],` portion in the route group. Middleware can also be applied to individual routes on a per need basis.

Comment: I am confused because isn't 'web' a $middlewareGroups and 'auth' a $routeMiddleware? So how could they both be middle ware? Also when I applied this when I hit my login view and login controller. It redirects until I reach the maximum number of redirects.

Comment: yes, but keep in mind web and auth are just aliases, the kernel will push them onto the middleware stack individually. Move your Auth::routes() call to the very top. I remember reading something about them needed to be prioritized first.

Comment: Try changing protected $redirectTo = '/register'; to your test route also, that could be causing the redirect loop.

Comment: I am still redirect to login over and over again. I changed the LoginController to protected $redirectTo = '/register';. Thanks for all your help. I am now going through the class on the LoginRegister to see If I can dd() somewhere to find the flow. However I have done it to all the methods on AuthenticatesUsers and none were effected. However It does at least hit the LoginController constructor. As well as getting passed assigning middleware. What Should I check next. It doesn't matter which page I goto in my routes they all redirect to login and go into some redirect loop.

Comment: It seems to be related to what we put in mapWebRoutes() on the RouteServiceProvider. I changed it to Route::middleware('web','auth')->namespace($this->namespace)->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));. Would that work?